# Why does arduino init() break timers?

Tags: timer, arduino, counter, program-entry-point, avr

This program toggles an LED on pin PB7 (pin 13 on Arduino with ATMega2560) every 50 000 clock cycles. It doesn't use any interrupts.

This works when it is defined as `int main()` but as `void setup()` TCNT1 seems to randomly bounce up and down without ever reaching the threshold. This does not change if we use e.g. timer 4 instead of timer 1.

```cpp
int main() {
  // Set pin PB7 to output
  // equivalent to pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
  DDRB |= 1 << 7;
  
  // Timer/Counter Control Register for timer 1: set Clock Source to clk/1 no prescaling
  TCCR4B |= (1 << CS10);

  for (;;)
  {
    // TODO if the counter/timer has reached the threshold
    if(TCNT4 >= 50000) {
      // Toggle PB7: if it was high, make it low, and if it was low, make it high
      PORTB ^= (1 << 7); 
      // TODO reset timer
      TCNT4 = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I do this with Arduino?

Comment: Arduino starts all timers in 8b mode so PWM on corresponding pins is working just by enabling the output... Maybe that is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As seen in Arduino init.c](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/9f8d27f09f3bbd1da1374b5549a82bda55d45d44/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L289), All timers are set to 8 bit for PWM, so TCNT1 never goes past 255.

To fix, call e.g. `cbi(TCCR4A, WGM40);` for timer 4 and be aware that this will probably break PWM for that timer.